# Android custom list view row layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have defined following layout which contains TextView, CheckBox and ProgressBar. I have two questions:-

1. When I clicked on list item, it automatically get sorted from Ascending to descending and vice versa, what might be wrong in my implementation?
2. If I kept the visibility of Checkbox to true then I am not getting the onListItemClick() event.

Please find layout below, I am newbie to android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textUrl"
    android:layout_width="318dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textUrl"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Below is custom adapter class that I am using.

```
 public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItemData>
{
    Context mContext;
    int mlayoutResourceId;
List<ListItemData> mlistData = null;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context,List<ListItemData> objects) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.custom_listview_row2, objects);

    mContext = context;
    mlistData = objects;
}       

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder vh;
    if (null == v)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_row2, parent,false);
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.mUrlTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textUrl);
        vh.mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        vh.mCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        v.setTag(vh);
    }
    else
    {
        vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    ListItemData itemData = mlistData.get(position);
    vh.mUrlTextView.setText(itemData.mUrlName);
    vh.mProgressBar.setProgress(itemData.mProgressValue);
    return v;
}
```

}

Code for ListActivity

```
    public class CustomListViewActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    //List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
        ArrayList<ListItemData> list = new ArrayList<ListItemData>();

        for (int idx = 0; idx < 10;idx++)
        {
        ListItemData item = new ListItemData("", 0);
        item.mUrlName = String.format("www.url-%d.com", idx);
        item.mProgressValue = idx*10;
        list.add(item);
    }       
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override   
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     ListItemData item = (ListItemData)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
     Toast.makeText(this, String.format("%s - %d", item.mUrlName,item.mProgressValue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: What Do you mean it is getting sorted when you click? How does your code look? If this is happening it has something to do with your code not the layout. How are you iflating the listview in code?

Comment: Hi coder_for_life22, added custom adapter class that I am using.

Comment: When you click on an item your list items are being rearranged?

Comment: Yes, ascending to descending and vice versa. I my case they are getting rearrange on text in TextView.

Comment: Where are you implementing your onlistclick code?

Comment: In class CustomListViewActivity, please see the code. Added just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for below question

> If I kept the visibility of Checkbox to true then I am not getting the
>   onListItemClick() event.

Answer - Set the focusable of Textview, checkbox and progress bar as well as relative layout   to false.

Answer (score 0):

Also found the answer for #2.

**When I clicked on list item, it automatically get sorted from Ascending to descending and vice versa, what might be wrong in my implementation?**

The problem was because my ViewHolder class. This initially like shown below

```
    final class ViewHolder 
    {   
        public static TextView mUrlTextView;
        public static ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        public static CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }
```

When I changed it as below, things started working fine :)

```
class ViewHolder 
{   
    public  TextView mUrlTextView;
    public  ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public  CheckBox mCheckBox;
}
```

Since the class was static, the tag value was pointing to same instance. Now after doing above change in ViewHolder class each item in list holds separate instance to view holder object. And things started working as expected.

Lesson learned - Never make any class static unless it is absolutely necessary .... :) :)